# Change output text of woocommerce variable product drop down

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hello I found this code on stackoverflow and am attempting to implement it into my site. The issue I am having is that once the foreach loop is complete, it returns the variable names as "3.0-centimeters" instead of "3.0 centimeters" for example. I have changed some code to display some changes but once I added my code in it does not show out of stock products anymore. Sometimes the "Out of Stock" text does not show up on the variable product drop down when I add code.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', 'customizing_variations_terms_name', 999, 1 );

function customizing_variations_terms_name( $term_name ) {

global $product;
// Get available product variations
$product_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

// product_variation terms are normalized to lowercase with
// spaces replaced by dashes.
// if your term name contains capital letters or spaces i.e. 'SIZE 6'
// the product variation will be lowercase with dashes, i.e. 'size-6'

     $term_name = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($term_name));


foreach ( $product_variations as $product_variation ) {
    if( isset( $product_variation['attributes'] ) ) {
        $key = array_search($term_name, $product_variation['attributes']);

        if( $key !== false && ! $product_variation['is_in_stock'] ) {
            return $term_name . ' - Out of Stock';
        }
    }
}

return $term_name;
}
```

What I've tried is changing the code to:

```
foreach ( $product_variations as $product_variation ) {
    if( isset( $product_variation['attributes'] ) ) {
        $key = array_search($term_name, $product_variation['attributes']);

        if( $key !== false && ! $product_variation['is_in_stock'] ) {
            **$term_name = str_replace('-', ' ', strtolower($term_name));**
            return $term_name . ' - Out of Stock';
        }
    }
}
**$term_name = str_replace('-', ' ', strtolower($term_name));**
return $term_name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want variation names to be formatted - just drop this line of code `$term_name = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($term_name));`

Comment: @yunjeffy, any reaction?